# C++ Visitor Pattern and Polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class, virtual-functions

The following code is a simplified version of a VisitorPattern I have implemented on my project.

```
#include <iostream>
class AVisitor {
public:
    virtual void visit(class A *) = 0;
};

class ExtendedVisitor : public AVisitor {
public:
    virtual void visit(class B *) = 0;
};

class A {
public:
    virtual void accept(AVisitor *visitor) {
        std::cout << "Call accept of A" << std::endl;
        visitor->visit(this);
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void accept(AVisitor *visitor) override {
        std::cout << "Call accept of B" << std::endl;
        B *just_this = this;
        visitor->visit(just_this);  //why this calls to visit(A*)
        visitor->visit((B*) just_this); //useless casting 
    }
};

class ActualVisitor : public ExtendedVisitor {
public:
    void visit(A *x) override {
        std::cout << "Call visit on A*" << std::endl;
    }
    void visit(B *x) override {
        std::cout << "Never called" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    ActualVisitor visitor;
    A *a = new B();
    a->accept(&visitor);
}
```

I don't understand why the accept method of class B calls to the visitor(A*) method instead of visitor(B*). The main function prints

```
Call accept of B
Call visit on A*
Call visit on A*
```

Instead, the following code behaves as I expected:

```
#include <iostream>

class AVisitor {
public:
    virtual void visit(class A *) = 0;
    virtual void visit(class B *) = 0;
};

class A {
public:
    virtual void accept(AVisitor *visitor) {
        std::cout << "Call accept of A" << std::endl;
        visitor->visit(this);
   }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void accept(AVisitor *visitor) override {
        std::cout << "Call accept of B" << std::endl;
        B *just_this = this;
        visitor->visit(just_this);  //now it works
        visitor->visit((B*) just_this);  
    }
};

class ActualVisitor : public AVisitor {
public:
    void visit(A *x) override {
        std::cout << "Call visit on A*" << std::endl;
    }
    void visit(B *x) override {
        std::cout << "Call visit on B*" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    ActualVisitor visitor;
    A *a = new B();
    a->accept(&visitor);
}
```

It now prints:

```
Call accept of B
Call visit on B*
Call visit on B*
```

The problem then seems to be the inheritance of the AVisitor class. I wonder why this happens and what is the proper way to design a VisitorPattern with "specialized" visitors (here ExtendedVisitor can also visit a B object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `B::accept` has the following signature:

```
void accept(AVisitor *visitor) override;
```

So, let's check the interface of `AVisitor`. It has

```
virtual void visit(class A *) = 0;
```

and that is all it has (in your first version). It is true that `ExtendedVisitor` has

```
virtual void visit(class B *) = 0;
```

but that *does not* override the method in `AVisitor`. In fact, your second version can help you see why. Since

```
virtual void visit(class A *) = 0;
virtual void visit(class B *) = 0;
```

can reside together in the same class (they are overloads in your second version), then they are distinct methods in this respect.

Comment: ActualVisitor class overrides both visit(A*) and visit(B*) methods, so since the signature of accept is accept(AVisitor * visitor), by polymorphism I expect that a call to visitor->visit(B*) to choose the correct method. What am I missing?

Comment: Your code doesn't refer to the interface of `ActualVisitor`, but rather to that of `AVisitor`. The *overloaded* virtual function in `ActualVisitor` is *not* an override of the method in `AVisitor`.

Comment: I see, you are right. Then if ActualVisitor does not override visitor(B*), it means that I have a non-abstract class that does not implement all the pure virtual functions (here visit(A*) and visit(B*)) ? or visit(A*) is the implementation of both visit(A*) and visit(B*) pure virtual functions ?

Comment: If it would not override `visitor(B*)`, you would indeed have a build error.

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing Visitor incorrectly. Here's the right way:

```
class AVisitor {
public:
    virtual void visit(class A *) = 0;
    virtual void visit(class B *) = 0;
    // virtual void visit(class C *) = 0; etc
    // a separate function for every class in your hierarchy
};
```

and then

```
class ActualVisitor : public Visitor ...
```

There's no need for `ExtendedVisitor`.

Yes `AVisitor` must know about every class in your hierarchy. This is the principal drawback of this pattern.